# End conversation in Dialogflow Fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm making an agent for Dialogflow for Google. Someone can ask 3 questions and after 3 questions, the conversation has to end. I want to end the conversation in the Fulfillment Inline Editor when a counter is 3. How can I do this? I tried this:

```
function Question(agent){
   if (counter == 3){
        agent.end(`OK, see you next time`);
   }
   else{
        agent.add(`OK, What is your next question?`);

   }
}

let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Question 3', Question);
```

But this is not working. The Firebase logbook is not giving any errors and the agent is not responding. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you update your question with some additional information about your agent? What Integrations are you doing this for (Actions on Google? Facebook? Something else?) If you're getting an error, update the question to show the error. If it "isn't working", what does it do?

Comment: I'm making an agent where people can ask 3 questions. It is for Actions on Google. It does not give an error. When I do agent.close('....') then it gives an error that agent.close is not working and i found here https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/webhook-client webhookClient.end(responses) but that is not working ass well. The only feedback I got is that the agent is not working anymore.

Comment: @Kolien did you find the solution for this problem?